# Flot graph axis tick mark spacing

Tags: jquery, flot

I would like my xaxis tick marks to be evenly spaced on my chart. I have a tick array that specifies strings as the tick labels.
I have employee IDs (converted to strings) and how many support calls they have taken. I am using a bar graph. Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/richardadavenport/rHL5c/) and code:

```
var p = $('#chart');
var d = [
    {
        data: [[16719,2],[18600,1],[23541,3],[23822,3]]
    }
];
var o = {
    bars: { 
        show: true,
        lineWidth: 5,
        zero: false,
        align: "center"
    },
    xaxis: {
        ticks: [[16719,'Bob'],[18600,'Chris'],[23541,'Joe'],[23822,'Rich']]
    }
};
$.plot(p, d, o);
```

I know that flot is using the employee ids as numbers, which is why the spacing is the way it is. I want to override that and have it look like this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/richardadavenport/97Lq2/). However I need to keep the employee IDs intact.

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: If the employee ids are not shown on the plot, why do they need to remain "intact"?

Comment: @Mark, that's a good question. I am actually passing in all  employee IDs and not all of them will display on the chart due to the fact that the data shows agents that took calls (calls > 0). Because of the data we don't know exactly which agents to show on the chart, so ALL of the agents are "ticks". I updated my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/richardadavenport/rHL5c/) by adding more employee ids ("ticks").